# Cant access LocalHost from Browser

Tags: apache-2.2, php, domain, linux-networking, ip-address

I hav installed apache2 & php 5.3x on centos 6.3 by using following commands:

```
yum install httpd
yum install php
```

Now I'm trying to access php page from my local machine browser using following ur:

```
Http://LocalIpOfServer/info.php
```

I cannot access my above php page  from browser and when i check apache logs, it doesnt show any hit, though I am connected to server locally..
but i can see some text when i access it from centOS command line by:

```
lynx > Http://localip/info.php
```

I'm unable to understand why I can access this page even when php is installed and apache is also working..

Comment: Check the firewall configuration on the server to see if that is where your problem is.

Comment: I'm able to connect to server through putty... which means I have no connectivity issue with server...

Comment: SSH is one thing - HTTP is another. I would still check the firewall.

Comment: Please post a content of your `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` from the server

Comment: Okay its working.. After disabling ip tables it worked..

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Please add your comments as reply so that I may mark it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the firewall configuration to see if it allows HTTP traffic to be sent to the server.